# C# Get directory name and file name without extension

Tags: c#, directory, path

Is there a easy way, to get the directory name and file name without the extension?

Example:

```
This is my path: "C:\mydir\myfile.ext"

and I want to get this: "C:\mydir\myfile"
```

The only way I found was this:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\mydir\myfile.ext"), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("C:\mydir\myfile.ext"));
```

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you've already found?

Comment: I hoped, that there is something like "Path.GetDirectoryNameFileNameWithoutextension" 
and Resharper is telling me, that there is a possible null assignment.

Comment: You have a one-line solution that works, I don't see how it can get easier than that.

Comment: @Ayoub_B marked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the extension, call [Path.ChangeExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.changeextension?view=netcore-3.1) with the second parameter null:

`Path.ChangeExtension(@"C:\mydir\myfile.ext", null)`

Comment: That's it, thank you.